# Html2png conversion with custom size in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, pdf, html

I need to batch convert html files into png without white fields around the picture. The html file has a background with two lines of text upon it. The background image is attached with css code in the head section of the html file.
I tried some conversion options with `xhtmltopdf` but I ended up with A4 pdf with lots of white space around the actual picture. My original idea was to first create pdfs and then convert them into png. May be someone knows a better approach? Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Here's my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
.cover
{
    text-align: center;
    background: url(cover01.jpg) no-repeat ;
    width: 270px ;
    height: 396px ;
    padding: 15px center ;
    background-clip: border-box ;
    background-origin: border-box ;
    line-height: 130px ;
    font-size: x-large ;
}
.author
{
text-align:center
}
.booktitle
{
text-align:center
}
span
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cover" background="cover01.jpg">

<p class="author">Jean Ziminne</p>
<span>
<p class="booktitle">Deep into the steppe</p></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This python script should work just fine for you :) hopefully..

> https://github.com/paulhammond/webkit2png
>
> webkit2png is a command line tool that creates screenshots of webpages

Example usage

```
webkit2png http://www.google.com/             # screengrab google
webkit2png -W 1000 -H 1000 http://google.com/ # bigger screengrab of google
webkit2png -T http://google.com/              # just the thumbnail screengrab
webkit2png -TF http://google.com/             # just thumbnail and fullsize grab
webkit2png -o foo http://google.com/          # save images as "foo-thumb.png" etc
webkit2png -                                  # screengrab urls from stdin
webkit2png /path/to/file.html                 # screengrab local html file
webkit2png -h | less                          # full documentation"""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know much of Python though. Gonna try it later as I'm time-pressed at the moment. I could do the task with terminal for a file. And for multiple files I will try doing with a bash script.

Comment: Finally I have done the task with pdf conversion in-between and then `convert -crop widthxheight+X+Y 0001.pdf 0001.png`